# Redpanda cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, redpanda

[image]

Hello, I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm following [this guide](https://vectorized.io/docs/quick-start-kubernetes/#Install-and-connect-to-a-Redpanda-cluster) but I have encountered the attached issue.

Comment: You should describe the running pods before running that rpk command

Answer (score -1):

Try editing the DNS nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Change your existing nameserver to Google nameserver `8.8.8.8`.

You can comment existing nameserver and it should be something like this:

```
#nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Google DNS doesn't solve Kubernetes internal cluster name resolution or service discovery